# Insert two table rows, then join in relational table by ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that takes two names and two email addresses, then a single password.

I am looking to write multiple queries so that the names and emails get inserted in to one table, then the auto-incrementing IDs generated by the database for both of those get inserted into the second table along with the password.

I run one insert query, grab `last_insert_id`, then run the other and do the same.

As I'm using `last_insert_id` to grab the auto-incrementing values, is there any way to store both of these as a variable, so that I can easily insert both their relevant IDs into the second table at the same time? Once I use `last_insert_id` a second time, it seems to lose the first value.

Pointers on methods to use, or a general direction in which to head, would be much appreciated. I like figuring out the exact code to use on my own.

**EDIT:**

These are my queries, which work fine *except* the UIDs created are 1 and 2, but inserted in to the second table are IDs 0 and 1. Any idea why?

```
$your_query = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (NAME, EMAIL) VALUES ('$your_name', '$your_email')";
$your_id = (mysql_insert_id());
mysql_query($your_query);
$partner_query = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (NAME, EMAIL) VALUES ('$partner_name', '$partner_email')";
$partner_id = (mysql_insert_id());
mysql_query($partner_query);
$couples_query = "INSERT INTO COUPLES (UID_1, UID_2, PASSWORD, SALT) VALUES ('$your_id', '$partner_id', '$password', '$salt')";
mysql_query($couples_query);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use 2 physical variables?  Without writing code in comments, here is a solution: `$id1 = last_insert_id; perform_second_query; $id2 = last_insert_id; perform_query_with_both_ids`

Comment: don't? first, store the password after one-way hashing it. SHA256 should still be fairly secure (MD5 isn't, SHA1 is becoming more questionable by the year). Once you have that done, why do you want to store the password in a separate table? Also, why two usernames and two email addresses? Trying to do things yourself to find out how to do them is cool, but then at least pick something that makes sense =P

Comment: Because I want to make an account on the site for two people, effectively. Individual login emails, a shared password, and a way of connecting the two of them so that I can run select queries at a later point and just show information for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had some extra brackets around each `mysql_insert_id`, and it should have been run after the `mysql_query`.

```
$your_query = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (NAME, EMAIL) VALUES ('$your_name', '$your_email')";
mysql_query($your_query);
$your_id = mysql_insert_id();
$partner_query = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (NAME, EMAIL) VALUES ('$partner_name', '$partner_email')";
mysql_query($partner_query);
$partner_id = mysql_insert_id();
$couples_query = "INSERT INTO COUPLES (UID_1, UID_2, PASSWORD, SALT) VALUES ('$your_id', '$partner_id', '$password', '$salt')";
mysql_query($couples_query);
```